# Java AES Decryption get Decrypted Hex instead of Decrypted String

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

When trying to decrypt a Hex String in Java, I am able to decrypt the string but because the original data which was encrypted is not a String but actually 32 bit hexadecimal values.

The encrypted hex string is **"4ba3442d4bc3baf5126b7b271b359e42"**, and the key used here is **"ac00ac00ac00ac00ac00ac00ac00ac00"**

The output which im supposed to get as retrieve from *aes.online-domain-tools.com* is **"×  z   X      .   b   3   ý   .   ä   g   í   ý   b   Þ   ."** but as seen from this String, only zXb3gb is of a normal ASCII character and the others are the extended characters which in return becomes a � in the console which carries a int value of **65533** which in turn is not correct for my original data.

But if we see the output from *aes.online-domain-tools.com*, the ASCII VALUES of the extended ASCII characters IS the correct values of the **original data** but because it is not a normal ASCII character but an extended character, it becomes a � with value **65533** which will give me the wrong value while being casted to integer.

I was wondering rather than decrypting it to a String, am I able to directly decrypt the hex string into the hex string rather than decrypt to string and cast to int.

Currently this is my decryption code:

```
public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt)
{
    char[] ch=strToDecrypt.toCharArray();

    System.out.println("Test: " + ch);
    try
    {

        Cipher cipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");

        cipher2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);

        setDecryptedString(new String(cipher2.doFinal(Hex.decodeHex(ch))));            // Output as String eg: testingone


    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        System.out.println("Error while decrypting: "+e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

And this is the block of code I use to cast it to INT to retrieve the original value:

```
        System.out.println("String To Decrypt : " + strToDecrypt);

    final String decryptedString = getDecryptedString();
    char[]  asciiLine = decryptedString.toCharArray();

    for (char ch:asciiLine)
    {
        System.out.println("Decrypted : " + (int)ch+"  ");
    }

    System.out.println("TestDecrypted : " + test.getDecryptedString());
    System.out.println("StringDecrypted : " + decryptedString);
    System.out.println("DecodeDecrypted : " + Integer.decode(decryptedString));
```

Comment: The output of encryption is arbitrary bytes, not valid printable characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a byte array to a hex string in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your decryption itself seems just fine ... but your handling of the returned data is not...

doFinal returns a byte array

you are handling that by passing it to new String(...)

what you possibly want is to encode that bytearray as a hex number string

have a look here ... [How to convert a byte array to a hex string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java)

Comment: Oh my.. Thanks bro.. Managed to print the expected output already.. Thanks for the guide.. So it was a wrong method of handling the returned data..